# How to get Highchart plots plotted only for starting and ending points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/cpcrxnbn/

In this highchart all the points available has the plot markers filled with white color. But, how to get the plots only for starting and ending positions?

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: null // inherit from series
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable markers for whole serie and enable per particular points.

```
series: [{
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        data: [{
            y: 176.0,
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                fillColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: colors[0] // inherit from series
            }
        },
        135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, {
            y: 54.4,
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                fillColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: colors[0] // inherit from series
            }
        }]
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpcrxnbn/3/

Comment: Thanks. This what exactly I want!